# Textarea with white space detect

Tags: html

```
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
```

I want when I submit the textarea, the preview of textarea detect automatic white space.
So if I input in textarea with a white space, It will show preview with white space.

Example :

I want go
somewhere

In my case it always like this :
I want go somewhere 
(whereas I give white space after text"go")

Comment: Very confusing question. HTML itself does not provide a "preview" for textareas. However, if you submit it to a PHP page you can use `nl2br()` to convert linebreaks into html linebreaks. Before doing so you need to use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape HTML tags unless everyone using that form is trusted enough to enter arbitrary html.

Comment: So that's actually what you are looking for? Great, posted it as an answer. The next time please make your question more clear and tag it properly (e.g. [tag:php] when using PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML itself does not provide a "preview" for textareas. However, if you submit it to a PHP script you can use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) to convert linebreaks into html linebreaks.

Before doing so you need to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to escape HTML tags unless everyone using that form is trusted enough to enter arbitrary html.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use some RichTextbox control to get the actual text that can be render in HTML correctly. when you press enter it doesn't mean that your text will append (HTML Break element)

in your code.

In HTML you need **HTML BR** when user hit enter. similar case will apply for other white space characters.

You can modify your TextArea to append the special HTML tags when whitespace entered. instead i suggest you to use RichTextBox (WYSIWYG)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can detect both new lines and blank spaces like this

```
$text = $_REQUEST['text_area_value'];
replace($text, " ", "&nbsp;"); // show blank spaces
replace($text, "\r\n", "<br/>") // show new lines
```